# Question about using substitution + Jacobian for integration in a concrete example

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution, jacobian

I am new to calculus and was hoping for some feedback re the following question and my proposed answer. Many thanks in advance.

> Parallelogram $D$ in the first quadrant has corners at $(0,0)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,4)$ and $(1,2)$. Calculate $$\iint_D xy \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.$$

My answer:

The parallelogram is bordered by:

$$y = 2x,\ y = 2x-2,\ y = x,\ y = x+1.$$

Therefore,

$$2x-2\leq y \leq 2x,$$
$$-2\leq y -2x \leq 0$$

and

$$x\leq y \leq x+1,$$
$$0\leq y - x \leq 1.$$

Let's define $u=y-2x,\ v=y-x$, then

$$\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}=\begin{vmatrix}-2 & 1 \\ -1 &1\end{vmatrix}=-1,$$
so the Jacobean is also $-1$, with absolute value $1$.

$$xy=(-u+2v)(v-u)=u^2-3uv+2v^2$$

$$\int^1_0dv\int^0_{-2}u^2-3uv+2v^2du=\int^1_0dv[\frac{1}{3}u^3-\frac{3}{2}u^2v+2v^2u]^0_{-2}$$

Therefore
$$\int^1_0\frac{8}{3}+6v+4v^2dv=[\frac{8}{3}v-3v^2-\frac{4}{3}v^3]^1_0=7$$

Comment: Your first double integral doesn't even contain "$\mathrm dv$", could you fix that? Also are you mixing the notations $\int \mathrm du \cdots$ and $\int \cdots \mathrm du$? Please stick to one notation for the sake of readability.

Comment: @christoph Sorry, there was a typo there: just fixed it...

Comment: I might’ve instead parameterized the region as $(x,y)=u(1,2)+v(2,2)$, $u,v\in[0,1]$. This gives you the substitution you need and the corresponding Jacobian directly without needing to invert anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct, although you should fix some minor problems already pointed out by Christoph. In this specific case you could also do very well without the change of variables, just by splitting the integral:
$$
\iint_D xy dx dy = \int_0^2\int_{y/2}^y xy \,dx dy + \int_2^4 \int_{y-1}^{y/2+1} xy \,dx dy.
$$

Comment: Note that splitting a parallelogram in general would yield three integrals. In this case the points $(1,2)$ and $(2,2)$ share the same $y$-coordinate so we can get away with only two integrals.

Comment: @Christoph I understand, this is why I said that "In this specific case...".